# Using PHP to retrieve Google Spreadsheet as HTML

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-sheets

I'm thinking that someone might of already solved this problem. I tried to look at the Spreadsheets API and there's no mention of being able to download the file. cURL might be an option but I'd rather not get into the hassle of authenticating / POSTing manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [Dynamic FAQ Section w/ jQuery, YQL & Google Docs](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/08/dynamic-faq-jquery-yql-google-docs/)if you want something like this.

Comment: Thanks ! The article mentions using the Spreadsheets publishing options, from which I can then get a URL and retrieve the HTML using cURL.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out: http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html

Although C# this will help too: [How to download Google SpreadSheets using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943995/how-to-download-google-spreadsheets-using-c)

Comment: I had looked to the Spreadsheets API and it's only returning data as XML, which I would then need to transform to HTML. The SO answer however is interesting, although I guess I'll use the much simpler solution I've read in the article the @dragosplesca mentioned, which is using the publishing options to set an URL for the spreadsheet.

Comment: Sounds good cheers mate, I believe the reason you are only seeing xml is because that is how google is storing your spreadsheet data.